# How to draw 8 lines away from every point in a layer using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, point, line, distance, nearest-neighbor

In QGIS I have a layer of many points, and I am trying to draw 8 lines of radius, r, from each point outwards, in the eight windrose directions (N, NE, .. etc). What is one method that can be used to do this? I know I can draw lines with the Line Capture tool, but I am not sure how to automate this process.

The black lines in the image below show the desired lines which need to be created for each point.
[image: Example of desired lines]

Comment: If this is a one-time task, then `Advanced Digitizing panel` is what you need. https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html?highlight=advanced#the-advanced-digitizing-panel Otherwise, you can try making a script in python using QGIS API: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Geometry by expression** with output geometry type line and expression below. Adjust the distance parameter:

```
collect_geometries(
array_foreach(array:=generate_series(start:=0, stop:=315, step:=45), expression:=make_line($geometry,  project(point:=$geometry, distance:=2000, azimuth:=radians(@element)))))
```

Output will be a multipart star for each point, convert to individual lines with **Multipart to Singleparts**

**Field Calculate** a direction string field with:

```
with_variable(name:='az', value:=
round(degrees(azimuth(start_point($geometry), end_point($geometry))),0), expression:=
case
    when @az=0 then 'N'
    when @az=45 then 'NE'
    when @az=90 then 'E'
    when @az=135 then 'SE'
    when @az=180 then 'S'
    when @az=225 then 'SW'
    when @az=270 then 'W'
    when @az=315 then 'NW'
    else 'ERROR'
end
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Depending on how you want the lines created (for display or as a layer), one option would be with a Geometry Generator expression under the Symbology tab of the Layer Properties:

[image]

[image]

Essentially you create a line by projecting each point by **radius** units in each of the 8 windrose directions (pi * N / 4 in radians, for N = 0 to 7):

```
with_variable('radius',50,
    collect_geometries(
        make_line($geometry,project($geometry,@radius,pi()*0/4)),
        make_line($geometry,project($geometry,@radius,pi()*1/4)),
        make_line($geometry,project($geometry,@radius,pi()*2/4)),
        make_line($geometry,project($geometry,@radius,pi()*3/4)),
        make_line($geometry,project($geometry,@radius,pi()*4/4)),
        make_line($geometry,project($geometry,@radius,pi()*5/4)),
        make_line($geometry,project($geometry,@radius,pi()*6/4)),
        make_line($geometry,project($geometry,@radius,pi()*7/4))
    )
)
```

[image]

If you want to convert this to a layer, you can use the same expression in the **Geometry by expression** tool from the Processing Toolbox.